# Setting lazy static variable first initializes then assigns?

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, static, lazy-initialization

I realize that `static` variables are implicitly `lazy`, which is really great. Doing the below will not create the instance until it's first called:

```
static var test = Test()
```

However, assigning a new instance to the `static` variable initializes the original, then assigns the new instance which is troubling for me:

```
SomeType.test = AnotherTest() //Initializes Test then AnotherTest type
```

To give more context on what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to setup a pure Swift dependency injection using [this article](http://www.danielhall.io/a-swift-y-approach-to-dependency-injection). It's not working so well when swapping the types out in my unit tests because the original type always gets initialized when assigning the mock type.

Here's a more fuller, playground sample:

```
protocol MyProtocol { }

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    init() { print("MyClass.init") }
}

////

struct MyMap {
    static var prop1: MyProtocol = MyClass()
}

protocol MyInject {

}

extension MyInject {
    var prop1: MyProtocol { return MyMap.prop1 }
}

////

class MyMock: MyProtocol {
    init() { print("MyMock.init") }
}

// Swapping types underneath first initializes
// original type, then mock type :(
MyMap.prop1 = MyMock()

prints: MyClass.init
prints: MyMock.init
```

How can I make `MyMap.prop1 = MyMock()` not first initialize the original `MyClass` first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need lazy loading. Try this:

```
struct MyMap {
    private static var _prop1: MyProtocol?
    static var prop1: MyProtocol {
        get { return _prop1 ?? MyClass() }
        set(value) { _prop1 = value }
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
struct MyMap {
    private static var _prop1: MyProtocol?
    static var prop1: MyProtocol {
        get {
            if _prop1 == nil {
                _prop1 = MyClass()
            }
            return _prop1!
        }
        set(value) { _prop1 = value }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa, why does this work??!.. Is this a bug in Swift or was this intentional?

Comment: Its as intended by swift. A var needs a value as long as it exists. This value may be nil or a concrete one. Your var can not be nil by your definition, therefore you have to specify a value (or compile throw an error). It doesn't matter if you call the get or set. Swift has to ensure that your var has a value before working with it. Thats what apple call "swift is save".

Comment: @codealchimist But `static` stored properties are lazily loaded – it shouldn't *have* to call the property initialiser if it's first assigned to before being loaded. But that's just currently how Swift behaves.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `static` stored property initialisers are thread safe, whereas lazily loading like in your second example is not thread safe.

Comment: @Hamish True both comments. There was a bug report for it too, maybe it will change in future swift versions and static isn't lazy anymore or it works as expected from a lazy var. Think it will be the first one for compatibility reasons. We will see..

Comment: Thx @Hamish for pointing out the thread-safety. I wrapped the getter in a serial queue and worked great. I was able to prove that it worked by calling `MyMap.prop1` with `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 1000)`.

Comment: For reference: ```
get {
    guard _prop1 == nil else { return _prop1! };
    queue.sync { if _prop1 == nil { _prop1 = MyClass() } };
    return _prop1!
}
```