# How do closures capture primitive values in local scope

Tags: ios, swift, closures, capture

```
func start() {
    var num = 1
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
        num += 1
    }
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
        print(num)
    }
}
```

Running the method above prints 2, 3, 4, etc every second.
How does the second timer know about the current value of `num` if it captures its own copy of `num`? or does it throw `num` into some sort of a reference type container and actually capture the pointer to `num` ? Let me know if the question is unclear.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642073/swift-does-closure-have-references-to-constants-or-variables

Comment: Quite an elegant little demonstration, nicely done.